# XSL FO content page differs for left and right pages

Tags: xsl-fo

Is it possible to have different page borders for Left page and right page content. For instance left page region-body will have border on left side alone; Right page "region-body" with right side border alone.

I am able to achieve different header and footer for left/right pages. For the page contents border should be placed depending on left/right pages.

I have used 2 simple page master for left and right content pages; but page master did n't support borders and resulted in the Exception "Border for region body should be zero".
Here is he sample code:

```
<fo:layout-master-set>
  <fo:simple-page-master master-name="left_pages">
    <fo:region-body margin-top="20mm" margin-bottom="10mm" border-left="1"  />                       
  </fo:simple-page-master>

  <fo:simple-page-master master-name="right_pages">
    <fo:region-body margin-top="20mm" margin-bottom="10mm"   border-right="1"/>                  
  </fo:simple-page-master>    
</fo:layout-master-set>
```

Thank you.

Comment: @Hobbes: margin is not an issue; but need to have borders..

Comment: you have to use a workaround to create borders here, see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In XSL-FO, there is a difference between [borders and margins](http://www.w3schools.com/xslfo/xslfo_blocks.asp). You can't [set a border for the body region](http://www.w3schools.com/xslfo/obj_region-body.asp), you have to use a margin instead.

To get a border for the bodyregion, you have to use a workaround.

- you can add the border as an image to the Start region. You can insert a large graphic in this region and it will extend across the page. The simplest way to create the border image is to use [SVG code](http://edutechwiki.unige.ch/en/XSLT_to_generate_SVG_tutorial) to create a rectangle.
- another option is to use a block-container on each page that has an absolute position and size (the same size as the body region).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Apache FOP to process your fo file, you can avoid the error message about region borders by using the **-r** (for **r**elaxed validation) command line option:

```
fop -r input.fo output.pdf
```

You will still get a *warning* telling you that region borders should be 0, but processing will continue and the borders will be created.

Comment: Are you sure? As far as I know, Saxon is an XSLT processor (transforms XML into XSL-FO using XSLT), and you need a formatter to create a PDF from the XSL-FO file. The other formatters I know of, both  [RenderX XEP](http://www.renderx.com/reference.html#Border_Padding) and [AntennaHouse XSLFormatter](http://www.antennahouse.com/CSSInfo/extension.html#IDABKMGB) support region borders with no special configuration.